# Strange editing behavior

Tags: feature-request, edits

Wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169877/the-difference-between-segment-fault-and-stack-smashing-detected/35170007#35170007).

Immediately edited it as I usually do to fix a couple of problems.

Then I save the edited post 1 minute later, I'm surprised to see that someone else (@a...) edited it as well! His changes are shown - not mine.

Then another minute later - he probably saw my changes pending - the post showed my version, finally.

I see a problem here

- Other people (at least, with lower rep) shouldn't be able to edit a post when it has just been posted - say during the 5 first minutes (these 5 minutes are not logged when the OP makes edits).

Comment: I only see one edit. It sounds like your first edit was made during the grace period, then the other user edited your question. Also, your edit would not be pending, as you made the original post. If the edit is wrong, you can change it. I'm sure what the problem is here.

Comment: An lot of people write a post and then immediately leave the site (for whatever reason). 5 minutes with no one able to correct issues with the post could lead to some serious, and entirely avoidable, down voting.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Believe me - could be a bug... His edits was live, ahead of mine for about a minute, and showed "Edited" by him ; no trace in the edits log since it was during the grace period, I guess. Maybe he did a rollback... then my changes appeared...(?) A bit strange..

Comment: @BSMP People with at least enough rep, say, 2k+ rep, do edit their post a lot during the first 5 minutes. Maybe not 5, but at least 2 minutes should be "protected". And with all the ajax going on, if OP enters edit mode, SO knows if OP is still on the page/editing or not...

Answer (score 3):

If your post isn't finished, and you're not ready for other people to see it, evaluate its quality, and fix any mistakes that you might have in it, then **don't post it yet**.  If you're constantly going back and editing every post right away then it's a sign that you need to spend more time editing your posts *before you post them*.

Comment: Many high rep users post quickly to be first posters. Then they edit to add more information within the first 5 minutes. At 139k you never did that?

Comment: @ringø I don't intentionally post answers that have mistakes, errors, or are otherwise unfinished, no.  Nor do I regularly see others doing so either.  People will occasionally post *entirely complete and acceptable* answers with the intention of editing them to add additional ancillary information, which is *radically* different.

Comment: "I don't intentionally post answers that have mistakes, errors, or are otherwise unfinished". Of course.

Comment: @ringø And yet you feel that everyone that every posts an answer virtually always posts an unfinished answer, which is why we should assume as much and prevent edits to recently posted answers so that the OP can finish them?

Comment: And who would "intentionally" post "answers that have mistakes, errors", seriously? Your last comment refers only to the "finished" part I suppose. There is a difference between "finished / acceptable" and "complete". "Acceptable" is when the post answers the question and may receive an "Accept" from the OP. "Complete" is usually reached within the 5 minutes grace period, adding other information. Between "Acceptable" and "Complete" people edit their own post. That happens a lot.

Comment: @ringø It happens from time to time.  It's not a particularly frequent behavior.  But if the originally posted answer is a finished and acceptable answer, then why in the world would we need to lock it from editing for 5 minutes to prevent other people from fixing its mistakes?